# Recycleview does not load images from json url

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I'm facing an strange problem indeed. I was following a tutorial from this link https://github.com/SaurabhKukreja/MyRecyclerViewExample where he has used Recycleview to load images from json.

Inside Homefragment he used the url json with below structure

```
[{
    "name": "Tom Hardy",
    "image": "https://api.androidhive.info/json/images/tom_hardy.jpg",
    "phone": "(541) 754-3010"
},
```

and when app is compiled ..the image sucessfully loads. But now when I replace image url with my own image which I have hosted in 00webhost , then image don't load.

Here is the link for same image from my hosting account

```
https://contact1881.000webhostapp.com/images/tom_cruise.jpg
```

what really I am doing wrong here?? Please kindly help me

Here is the Homefragment

```html
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener , Response.ErrorListener {

    View view;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Context context;
    private List<Model> contactList  = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url ="https://api.androidhive.info/json/contacts.json";
    Button btn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
        context = getContext();
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        getContactList();
        return view;
    }

    private void getContactList(){
        Log.d("TEST","Getting Contact list");
        Controller.getInstance(context).makeNetworkCalls(Request.Method.GET,url,this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Object response) {
        Log.d("TEST","Got The response" +response);
        if (response == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't fetch the contacts! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        List<Model> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Model>>(){}.getType());
        contactList.addAll(items);
        MyAdapter rcAdapter = new MyAdapter(contactList,context);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    }
}
```

and Image loader class is

```html
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

Adapter class is

```html
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Model> mDataset;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView nameText;
        public TextView phoneText;
        public NetworkImageView image;
        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nameText = v.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            phoneText = v.findViewById(R.id.phone_text);
            image = v.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Position: "+getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Model> myDataset, Context mCOntext) {
        Log.d("TEST",myDataset.get(0).getName());
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mCOntext).getImageLoader();
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        //holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
        Log.d("TEST","Printing Names onBindView Holder"+mDataset.get(position).getName());
        holder.nameText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
        holder.phoneText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.image.setImageUrl(mDataset.get(position).getImage(),mImageLoader);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post Adapter class

Comment: @UmangBurman Please check

Comment: Post code from: NetworkImageView and what setImageUrl(String, ImageLoader) does

Comment: are you getting the image string at `mDataset.get(position).getImage()`

Comment: @UmangBurman  please check this whole source code https://github.com/SaurabhKukreja/MyRecyclerViewExample  ..I have  borrowed this from....I'm just a begigner in android and trying to understand how errror occurs and resolve them...I wanted to load my own images I have hosted upon 00Webhost but images didn't load ....but instead if i pasted url in browser of pc then it sucessfully show same images from both url but on android device only one url launches the image but another don't .please follow the above link for source code.

Comment: Bro, In My Opinion, You don't need so much. Too much of extra coding just to display 3 data in the RecyclerView. I personally think it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

**My Suggestion :**

If you want to refer Volley Library for displaying images or any other data in RecyclerView, then follow the below tutorial:

[Volley RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

or (better option)

If you want to refer Retrofit Library for displaying images or any other data in RecyclerView, then follow the below tutorial:

[Retrofit RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

IMO, go for Retrofit Library, it's Good and better than Volley.

Happy Coding.